# Execute permission in maven-dependency-plugin during copying and unpacking

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin

I've got strange behavior with using maven-dependency-plugin. 
When I use '`copy`' goal of maven-dependency-plugin and then I unzip dependency archive manually
I have -rwx permissions on my files.

But when I do '`unpack`' goal, then I have just -rw permissions for all my files from this dependency.

Comment: Do you know what umask is set to on your machine?

Comment: @ojblass yes, it is 0002

Comment: have you found a solution